# Converting a unique columns into SFrame headers with corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, graphlab, sframe

I have a tab-separated file:

```
$ echo -e 'abc\txyz\t0.9\nefg\txyz\t0.3\nlmn\topq\t0.23\nabc\tjkl\t0.5\n' > test.txt
$ cat test.txt
abc xyz 0.9
efg xyz 0.3
lmn opq 0.23
abc jkl 0.5

$ python
>>> from sframe import SFrame
>>> sf = SFrame.read_csv('test.txt', header=False, delimiter='\t', column_type_hints=[unicode, unicode, float])
[INFO] sframe.cython.cy_server: SFrame v2.1 started. Logging /tmp/sframe_server_1479718846.log
>>> sf
Columns:
    X1  str
    X2  str
    X3  float

Rows: 4

Data:
+-----+-----+------+
|  X1 |  X2 |  X3  |
+-----+-----+------+
| abc | xyz | 0.9  |
| efg | xyz | 0.3  |
| lmn | opq | 0.23 |
| abc | jkl | 0.5  |
+-----+-----+------+
[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

The goal is to achieve a different SFrame where there'll be one unique row made up of 'X1' and the columns are values from 'X2', i.e.:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+
|  X1 | xyz | opq |  jkl |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| abc | 0.9 | 0.0 |  0.5 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| efg | 0.3 | 0.0 |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| lmn | 0.0 | 0.23|  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

I've tried doing it without SFrame:

```
>>> import io
>>> with io.open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
...     for line in fin:
...             if line.strip():
...                     s,t,p = line.strip().split('\t')
...                     matrix[(s,t)] = float(p)
... 
>>> matrix
{(u'abc', u'jkl'): 0.5, (u'abc', u'xyz'): 0.9, (u'lmn', u'opq'): 0.23, (u'efg', u'xyz'): 0.3}

>>> col1, col2 = zip(*matrix.keys())
>>> [[matrix.get((c1,c2), 0.0) for c2 in col2] for c1 in col1]
[[0.5, 0.9, 0.0, 0.9], [0.5, 0.9, 0.0, 0.9], [0.0, 0.0, 0.23, 0.0], [0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.3]]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([[matrix.get((c1,c2), 0.0) for c2 in col2] for c1 in col1])
array([[ 0.5 ,  0.9 ,  0.  ,  0.9 ],
       [ 0.5 ,  0.9 ,  0.  ,  0.9 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.23,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.3 ,  0.  ,  0.3 ]])
>>> SFrame(np.array([[matrix.get((c1,c2), 0.0) for c2 in col2] for c1 in col1]))
Columns:
    X1  array

Rows: 4

Data:
+-----------------------+
|           X1          |
+-----------------------+
|  [0.5, 0.9, 0.0, 0.9] |
|  [0.5, 0.9, 0.0, 0.9] |
| [0.0, 0.0, 0.23, 0.0] |
|  [0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.3] |
+-----------------------+
[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

But that still don't get me the desired SFrame. **How should I convert the unique columns into SFrame headers with corresponding values?** I.e. achieve:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+
|  X1 | xyz | opq |  jkl |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| abc | 0.9 | 0.0 |  0.5 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| efg | 0.3 | 0.0 |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| lmn | 0.0 | 0.23|  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

There must be a simpler way to do this. Imagine that the unique no. of column elements can go up to 1,000,000 and resulting SFrame might be of size 1,000,000 X 1,000,000 thus the need for SFrame or HDF like data structure and not a numpy array or native python list of lists.

Comment: This is really trivial using a pandas DataFrame. Given the size of your data, is it possible for you to convert temporarily to the SFrame using `sd.to_dataframe()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is really trivial in pandas, using either `df.pivot(index='X1', columns='X2', values='X3')` or by doing `df.set_index(['X1','X2']).unstack('X2')` (see at end of this post).

It seems like neither exist in SFrame. (I could be wrong, never used SFrame until now but I couldn't find any evidence in the documentation).

You need to use [SFrame.unstack()](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.unstack.html) and [SFrame.unpack()](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.unpack.html) in order to achieve the desired result.

```
from sframe import SFrame
sf = SFrame.read_csv('test.txt', header=False, delimiter='\t', column_type_hints=[unicode, unicode, float])
```

Fist, unstack:

```
sf2 = sf.unstack(['X2', 'X3'], new_column_name='dict_counts')
sf2

X1      dict_counts
efg     {'xyz': 0.3}
lmn     {'opq': 0.23}
abc     {'jkl': 0.5, 'xyz': 0.9}
```

Then unpack:

```
out = sf2.unpack('dict_counts', column_name_prefix='')
out

X1      jkl     opq     xyz
efg     None    None    0.3
lmn     None    0.23    None
abc     0.5     None    0.9
```

Finally, you can fillna in order to replace `None` with `0` if you'd like:

```
for c in out.column_names():
    out = out.fillna(c, 0)
out


X1      jkl     opq     xyz
efg     0.0     0.0     0.3
lmn     0.0     0.23    0.0
abc     0.5     0.0     0.9
```

---

Another crude way of doing it might be to convert to it a pandas DataFrame in order to pivot it, but this might not work if your dataset is too big:

```
import pandas as pd
from sframe import SFrame
sf = SFrame.read_csv('test.txt', header=False, delimiter='\t', column_type_hints=[unicode, unicode, float])
sf = SFrame(data=sf.to_dataframe().pivot(index='X1', columns='X2', values='X3').fillna(0).reset_index())
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the detailed explanations!!

Comment: Note: Unpacking a huge dataset takes really long though. So is filling a sparse dataset with 0.0 ;P

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you give me an idea of the size of your data and how much time it takes?

Comment: 10,000,000,000 , I don't have the timing but it's less than one toilet break but more than 5 minutes for pandas. It's a lot slower in SFrame, i didn't really take note of the time.

Comment: `10,000,000,000` rows or elements (cells)?

Comment: cells, it's 100,000 * 100,000 ;P

Comment: Got it. Interesting that it's a lot slower in SFrame. I guess the point of SFrame is to be out-of-core, so maybe that makes sense.